# Why can't I assign this DataGridViewComboBoxCell to the cell I want?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I'm having a weird set of problems with my DataGridViewComboBoxCell objects. FYI, I am using the Cell rather than the Column because my data is organized by row, not by column.

My first problem is that I can't seem to get the assignment right to my DataGridView. It's fine when I do a straight assignment in my code:

```
Dim MyDropDown As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell()
'Code here to populate dropdown
MyForm.DataGridView1(col, row) = MyDropDown
```

I run into trouble when I try to use a procedure to do the same thing:

```
Dim MyDropDown As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell()
'Code here to populate dropdown
SetUpDataViewGridDropdown(MyDropDown, MyForm.DataGridView1(col, row))
```

. . .

```
Public Sub SetUpDataViewGridDropdown(ByRef dd As DataGridViewComboBoxCell, _
                                 ByRef ddTarget As DataGridViewCell)

ddTarget = dd
'Do some more interesting stuff here
End Sub
```

I don't get an error, but the DataGridView renders without displaying the dropdown. So the assignment doesn't seem to be happening. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

`MyForm.DataGridView1(col, row)` gets the cell currently in the `DataGridView`. So what you're doing in your function is just changing the referenced object of `ddTarget` variable, which is useless.

Try something like this :

```
Public Sub SetUpDataViewGridDropdown(ByRef dd As DataGridViewComboBoxCell, _
                             ByVal rowIndex As Int, _
                             ByVal columnIndex As Int)

MyForm.DataGridView1(columnIndex, rowIndex) = dd 
'Do some more interesting stuff here
End Sub
```